# file.exists() and file.createNewFile() not working properly?

Tags: java, file-io

Basicly, lets say I got `File f1 = new File("C:\\somedir\\batch1.bat");` and `File f2 = new File("C:\\somedir\\batch2.bat");` and I have 2 ifs

```
if(f1.exists() == false)
{
    showMessage("File 1 not detected, creating new...");
    f1.createNewFile();
}
else
{
    showMessage("File 1 detected, deleting it and creating new...");
    f1.delete();
    f1.createNewFile();
}
```

and

```
if(f2.exists() == false)
{
    showMessage("File 2 not detected, creating new...");
    f2.createNewFile();
}
else
{
    showMessage("File 2 detected, deleting it and creating new...");
    f2.delete();
    f2.createNewFile();
}
```

First if executes "else" code no matter if file exists or not, and second one executes "if" part, without creating new file. help please!

#### EDIT

My `showMessage(String msg)` method does `System.out.println(msg)` just so you know.

Comment: You need to check whether createNewFile return true. It won't work unless the directory exists and you have write access.

Comment: BTW: delete can fail too if a) it doesn't exist b) you don't have access c) the file is locked.

Comment: @StealthyHunter7 you can try [`File.mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) to attempt to create the parent directories. Note I would avoid using `File` in favor of the [NIO.2 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Comment: Where do I need to check if it returns true? Instead of exists() ? or after I call it? Thanks

Comment: @StealthyHunter7, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question title and body isn't helpful.  Combining, `file` and `exists`, for example, doesn't mean you're trying to see if a file exists.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're doing this at all. `new FileOutputStream(...)` creates the file anew anyway, and so do most other `FileOutputStream/Writer` and `PrintStream/Writer` constructors. Calling these `File` methods is usually a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm I'm sure not the problem but doing this is more readable:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(!f.exists()) { /* do something */ }
```

rather then:

```
if(f1.exists() == false)
    {
      ...
    }
```

also when deleting a file always check its return value:

```
if(f.delete()) {//deleted successfully
}else {//couldnt delete
   //show error message
}
```

and as PeterLawrey said you should do the same for `createNewFile()`:

```
if(f.createNewFile()) {//created successfully
}else {//couldnt create
   //show error message
}
```

and lastly always check for permissions before trying to do anything:

```
if(f.canRead()&&f.canWrite()) {//can read and write free to do what is needed
   //do stuff
}else {
}
```

Comment: It would be a comment, if only you could put readable code in a comment . :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes thats the only reason I didnt. But I am adding more to my answer to make it maybe more valuable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did provide me with information what went wrong. :D

Comment: Under Windows 7, canRead & canWrite can return false positives due to the UAC (under Java 6, haven't tested Java 7)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes UAC suuucks lol. but real programmers turned that off after the first install of their windows vista and up :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp yeah, but real programmers have to deal with real users, nuff said ;)